# preg_replace for youtube video

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Looks that I have some error in my script.

preg_replace does not work in this example:

This is an example that I use as $message:

```
<div class="videoss videoss1PUT2a5NafI"><a href="#" class="videoshow" id="1PUT2a5NafI"><div style="background:url(/i/play.png) center no-repeat,url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/1PUT2a5NafI/mqdefault.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:30%,cover;" class="pd39 mroim60"><div class="captn"></div></div></a></div>
```

I need the script to return:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PUT2a5NafI
```

from this example. This is my preg_replace:

```
$message = preg_replace("@\<div class=\"videoss videoss(.*?)\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"videoshow\" id=\"(.*?)\"><div style=\"background:url(/i/play.png) center no-repeat,url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/(.*?)/mqdefault.jpg) center no-repeat;background-size:30%,cover;\" class=\"pd39 mroim60\"><div class=\"captn\"></div></div></a></div>@si", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\\1", $message);
```

Unfortunately, i does not replace anything and returns $message as it is.

Comment: You're not escaping some characters that you should. E.g. `(` and `)` that you expect to be part of the string.

Comment: Thanks Jonnix, this solved the problem